# How do I print out a typedef item of type string?

Tags: visual-c++, typedef, cout

If I have a typedef item of type string how can I print it out using cout?  I keep getting the "can't convert from *typedefItemType* to string" message.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef string MyStrings[2]; 

...

MyStrings names = { "Brandon", "Programmer" };

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(names) / sizeof(string); i++)
{
   cout << names[i] << endl;
}
```